# Is it possible to use an old iPod as a display and extra processor for Raspberry Pi Zero W?

Tags: pi-zero-w

I want to put an old Apple iPod to good use and I thought using it for a Raspberry Pi was one. I want to use my old iPod to boost my Raspberry Pi Zero processing power and display things from it. Also, I don't want any Apple software or firmware on the iPod.

Comment: it is possible ... it would be extremely expensive

Comment: Is it possible to run VNC on an iPod? And why do you not want any Apple code on the iPod?

Comment: I don't want to do it through VNC. I want to wire my RPI directly into the screen and processor. I don't want any Apple code on the iPod so that it's not taking up the screen or processor. And why would it be expensive?